# Version numbers of dependencies in testing

Tags: community-official-site, .info, testing

If I'm submitting a test to the qa.drupal.org testbot, and my module requires a dev version of another module in order to function properly, is it adequate to declare the version in my module's .info file, or do I need to also specify version numbers in the test `DrupalWebTestCase::setUp()` where dependencies are declared for the test itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the **module.info** file docs: ( quite long, but informative )

### dependencies

An array of other modules that your module requires. If these modules are not present, your module cannot be enabled. If these modules are present but not enabled, the administrator will be prompted with a list of additional modules to enable and may choose to enable the required modules as well, or cancel at that point.

The string value of each dependency must be the module filename (excluding ".module") and should be written in lowercase like the examples below. Spaces are not allowed.

```
dependencies[] = taxonomy
dependencies[] = comment
```

In addition, `test_dependencies[]` can be used to indicate dependencies which are optional but recommended. At this writing they are supported only by Drupal.org's automated testing system. *They cause the testbots to check out the projects suggested*.

`test_dependencies[] = autoload`

If you need to specify that a certain module's version number is required Drupal 7 provides a way for this in the dependencies[] field. Version numbers are optional and only necessary if the module absolutely requires another module's specific version or branch.

The syntax for the dependencies[] field(s) is:

`dependencies[] = modulename (major.minor)`

Where major is the numeric major version number and minor is the numeric or alphanumeric minor version number. x can be used to denote any minor version. Some examples follow.

```
name = Really Neat Widget
description = An example module
dependencies[] = exampleapi (1.x)

test_dependencies[] = autoload (>7.x-1.5)
...
```

In the above .info code, the "Example" module requires an "Example API" module with the major version of 1 and any minor version.

`dependencies[] = exampleapi (1.0)`

This means that the module requires the 1.0 (and only the 1.0) version of the Example API module.

`dependencies[] = exampleapi (1.x)`

The above module requires any minor version of the module in the 1.x branch (1.0, 1.1, 1.2-beta4, etc.)

The `dependencies[]` property in the .info file can also optionally specify versions:

```
= or == equals (optional: equals is the default)
> greater than
< lesser than
>= greater than or equal to
<= lesser than or equal to
!= not equal to
```

`dependencies[] = exampleapi (>1.0)`

The above module requires any version greater than version 1.0.

You can optionally specify the core version number as well:

`dependencies[] = exampleapi (>7.x-1.5)`

The above module requires a 7.x version compatible version of the module and a version greater than 1.5.

Additionally, multiple version dependencies can be specified as comma-separated values within the parentheses:

`dependencies[] = exampleapi (>1.0, <=3.2, !=3.0)`

This facility can be used to specify a minimal core version by using system as the module name:

`dependencies[] = system (>=7.53)`

This makes the module require at least Drupal 7.53.

More info: http://drupal.org/node/542202#dependencies

Comment: I am not asking about the module.info file though, I'm asking about `DrupalWebTestCase::setUp()` I've already declared the dependency in my module.info file.

Comment: You asked "...is it adequate to declare the version in my module's .info file?" The module.info file should suffice to set those module dependencies, especially using `test_dependencies[]`